# Find the minimum number of values in a range whose sum is >= 75% of the sum of all values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with two columns.  Column A contains  a list of names and column B a list of numerical values associated with those names.

I need to find the minimum number of cells in column B  whose sum is greater than or equal to at least 75% of the sum of all the values in column B.

For those cells I need to return:

1. The cell count
2. The associated names from Column A

**Sample Data**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Name-01 | 10 |
| Name-02 | 20 |
| Name-03 | 15 |
| Name-04 | 40 |
| Name-05 | 10 |
| Name-06 | 6 |

In the sample data above the column B total is 100 so the minimum number of cells needed to achieve at least 75% of that is 3:

| Count: | 3 |
| --- | --- |
| Name-02 | 20 |
| Name-03 | 15 |
| Name-04 | 40 |

If possible no array formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the names in column `A2:A` that represent *at least* 75% of the sum of the values in column `B2:B`, filter by the running total. To guarantee that the result always matches or exceeds the target, you have to *subtract* the current value from the tally, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, sort(A2:B, 2, false), 
  names, choosecols(data, 1), 
  values, choosecols(data, 2), 
  target, 75% * sum(values), 
  tally, scan(0, values, lambda(a, c, a + c)), 
  filter(names, tally - values < target) 
)
```

With data like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| alice | 10 |
| bob | 20 |
| charly | 15 |
| dorothy | 39 |
| eve | 10 |
| frank | 6 |

...the formula will get results like this:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| david | 39 |
| bob | 20 |
| charly | 15 |
| alice | 10 |

(note: using `filter(data` instead of `filter(names` for illustration)